# Refer static resource of CSS in Lighting component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css

I have upload one CSS file in static resource may I know how can we refer it in Lightning Component ??

File Name uploaded as static Resource- bootstrap.css

Static Resource Name-CssFile

Also I have added the CSS code under style in component do i need to remove it.
Please advise ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Aura, use [`ltng:require`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apps_css_external_platform.htm):

```
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.CssFile}" />
```

In LWC, use [`loadStyle`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_third_party_library):

```
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import STATIC_RESOURCE_NAME from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/CssFile';

// ... some time later ... //
loadStyle(this, STATIC_RESOURCE_NAME).then(
  () => {
    // do whatever you need to do after styles load
  }
)
```

Comment: Hi I also want to refer JS file , How can i do that      scripts='/resource/Javascript'  have added this code in Lightning Component but i got an error !! Javascrip is the static resource Name

Comment: Error i got -This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. First, would you give us some details? (We're reporting this as error ID: -944567236!!    Pls Help on this

Comment: @user105921 use `{!$Resource.javascript}`.